# Bitwise operation substring in Java

Tags: java, substring, bitwise-operators

Imagine you'd have the binary or hex representation of a number. Let's take this:

```
int number  = 0xffffff;
// this would recover the third f, as a stand-alone value, value of third_f would be just f
int third_f = byteSubstring(number,2,1);
// third and fourth f, value of tf would be ff
int tf = byteSubstring(number,2,2);
// all except first, value of except_first would be fffff
int except_first = byteSubstring(number,1,5);
```

Using separate bitwise operations, pen & paper, I know how to extract all of them, but combining them in one generic function ...  :). Is there something already available in the JDK that can do this for numeric types?

Comment: Actually, I don't think you understand what you're writing quite. 0xf is FOUR bits, binary 1111, and the value of the "third f" would be `0x00f000` 0r `0x000f00` depending on how you're counting (your except_first function seems to be indexing from 1 not 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `size` and `offset` specified in bits. Traditionally the bits are numbered starting at the LSB.

You handle the `offset` by shifting right

```
result = x >>> offset
```

You handle the size by masking; `(1 << size) - 1` is the mask

```
result = result & ((1 << size) - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Java has the usual [bitwise operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) so you could just build a mask and `and` your data.

**EDIT**

Perhaps some example code will be a bit more usefull:

```
// be aware - this actually substrings a hex substring, using
// bit ops
int byteSubString(int number, 
                  int firstPos /* 0-indexed */, 
                  int length) {
        // tricky naming as hex = 2 byte per char!
        int mask = 0;
        switch (length) { //lookup table/array might be best here
        case 0: mask = 0; break;
        case 1: mask = 0xf; break;
        case 2: mask = 0xff; break;
        case 3: mask = 0xfff; break;
        case 4: mask = 0xffff; break;
        case 5: mask = 0xfffff; break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                 "Length of " + length + " not supported");
        }
        int tmp = (number >> (4*firstPos));
        tmp = (tmp & mask);
        System.out.println("Byte substring on " +
                       Integer.toHexString(number) + 
                       " starting at pos " + firstPos + 
                       " with length " + length + 
                       " uses mask " + Integer.toHexString(mask) + 
                       " results in " + Integer.toHexString(tmp));
        return tmp;
    }
```

Of course you could also just render the String to a hex representation and substring that. Might be faster and more readable :)

Comment: Indeed. But this is not helpful.

Comment: Why not? It doesn't seem difficult to write byteSubstring using bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

See the "format" syntax in [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) and combine with `String.format("%x", hexa)`.  For example `String.format("%x", 0xffffff)` returns the `String` "ffffff".  Then you can just write the methods you want as wrapper over this and `String.substring`.

However, it cannot deal with binary, but that's easier to code by hand.

Edit: actually `Integer.toBinaryString` also exists.

Comment: Integer.toHexString() does that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any functions in the standard library that does that.
Things that are alike are in `Integer` class, there are some functions that do some composed operations on bits.

You can code it yourself:

```
// offset and len are bits
// (so you multiply them by 4 if you want to get a hex representation)
int substring(int value, int offset, int len) {
  value >>>= (Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberofLeadingZeros(value)) - (offset + len);
  return value & ((1 << len) - 1);
}
```